# List of days between two dates in Exasol

Tags: sql, exasol

In PostgreSQL, it's fairly easy to generate a list of all days between two dates:

```sql
>>> select generate_series('2013-01-01'::date, '2013-01-06'::date, '1 day'::interval)::date i;

i
2013-01-01
2013-01-02
2013-01-03
2013-01-04
2013-01-05
2013-01-06
```

Is it possible to achieve the same result in Exasol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `connect by` to generate numbers and then convert that to dates:

```
with n as (
      select level - 1 as n
      from dual
      connect by level < 6
     )
select add_days(date '2013-01-01', n.n)
from n;
```

Answer (score 3):

Following SQL SELECT can be used for returning days list within the given interval similar to Gordon's solution as described at [create dates table on Exasol](http://www.kodyaz.com/exasol/create-dates-table-on-exasol-database-using-sql-date-functions-and-dual.aspx) article

```
select
 add_days(date '2013-01-01', level-1) as dates
from dual
connect by level <= days_between('2013-01-06','2013-01-01')+1
order by local.dates;
```